# MVC AreaRegistration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

**Where is Class AreaRegistration ?****strong text** Cannot find Class AreaRegistration in MVC 2 ?
I Have installed MVC 2 Preview 2 (Had Preview 1 instlled but not used)

using System; using    System.Collections.Generic; using    System.Linq; using System.Web; using    System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcAreasSingleProject.Areas.Blog
{
    public class Routes : AreaRegistration

Gives **missing using directive or an assembly reference error** (Same error RegisterRoutes)
Where is Class AreaRegistration ?

Answer (score 0):

double check your references to system.web.mvc to make sure that it is version 2.0.0  I had the same problems with AreaRegistration and forgot to check.

Answer (score 0):

It's in System.Web.Mvc assembly - make sure you've referenced version 2.0 (check Path and Version in Properties window after selecting reference in Solution Explorer)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.arearegistration.aspx